# SpriteKit didBeginContact called but not didEndContact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code, the `didBeginContact(contact:)` method is called but not `didEndContact(contact:)`.

```
// FIXME: This is a workaround until class vars are supported
let sharedContactHandler = ContactHandler()

class ContactHandler: NSObject, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    class var sharedHandler: ContactHandler {
        get {
            return sharedContactHandler
        }
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let bodyA = contact.bodyA
        let bodyB = contact.bodyB

        NSLog("Began contact")
        ...
    }

    func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let bodyA = contact.bodyA
        let bodyB = contact.bodyB

        NSLog("Ended contact")
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And in my scene,

```
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = ContactHandler.sharedHandler
```

I've searched around and can't find any reason why one should be called but not the other. I've made sure that the method signatures are correct and everything.

When two bodies come into contact, I see "Began contact" in the log but once they are no longer in contact, "Ended contact" never appears.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The didEndContact is only called when a node loses contact via movement. Are you removing the contact node from parent after contact is established? If yes, then you would not get a didEndContact message.

Comment: What exactly is happening during contact? I've noticed that if you programmatically change the sprite position/size when the contact occurs, it can throw off the physics engine too. (sorta what sangony said)

Comment: Actually yes, I am removing the node from the scene sometime during contact, I didn't even think about that but it makes sense. I'll have to come up with something else then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are removing the node from parent then you can also set the other node's contact code/BOOL to false.

Comment: @sangony could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: Whatever code you run if contact is lost, you can run when you remove one of the nodes from parent.

Comment: @sangony I'm dealing with the same problem - but I'm unable to update the `didEnd` contact manually after moving the node, and changing things like the `collisionBitMask` of the node do not work without `didEnd` first firing.