# SpriteKit didEndContact not being called

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicscontact

In my `didEndContact:` method I increment a "currentScore".

For some reason, **`didEndContact:` is not being called**, and hence the "currentScore" is not being incremented.  Any ideas why or what I should be looking for to debug this?

```
func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    guard goal!.barEnabled else { return }
    score += 1
}
```

Here is related code, let me know if I can add any other helpful details too:

```
var barEnabled:Bool {
    set {
        bar?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = newValue ? CollisionMask.Puck : CollisionMask.None
        bar?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = newValue ? CollisionMask.Goal : CollisionMask.None
    }
    get {
        return bar?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask == CollisionMask.Puck
    }
}
```

Comment: are you removing the sprite from the scene before didEndContact happens?  Because it will not get called then

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yeah I checked on that because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331799/spritekit-didbegincontact-called-but-not-didendcontact , but thanks for double checking with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to detect collisions, you'll have to set the `contactTestBitMask` of the `physicsBody`.

The `contactTestBitMask` of a `physicsBodys` and the `categoryBitMask` of another `physicsBodys` have to be not 0 when an binary AND operation is applied to the 2 integers for the detection to trigger.

In case you have not already, make sure that the `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` of the scene is set to `self` and that it implements the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`.

Comment: Double checked that I have `physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` and also that the Scene implements `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`, so that looks good, and thanks for explaining the detecting collisions just so I could check that I was doing the bit mask parts too.

Comment: I need a little bit more context in order to figure out why it's still not working.

Comment: I did get it working now, so I marked the answer but forgot to add a comment.  Thanks a lot!